# What is the origin and rank of this military uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image]Uncle got this, I believe in desert storm. Dunno how he got it and he didn't wanna talk about it so I didn't ask. Please help me identify the origin and rank.

Answer (score 27):

This is a [Soviet army junior officer's greatcoat](https://www.safar-publishing.com/post/soviet-army-winter-uniform) (двубортная шинель).

The shoulder boards are for a post-1943 [senior lieutenant of the infantry](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1943inf-pf10.png#mw-jump-to-license) - you can just barely see the second of 3 stars and the thin red line on the right shoulder board. Although notably this is identical to later designs, including the current [senior lieutenant of the Russian infantry](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) design - the only clue would be the edge piping and the shape of the board itself, as the post-1955 edge is cut diagonally rather than with a tented edge.

I can't precisely place the year of the coat itself as it was quite an enduring standard - it matches the appearance of 1943 coats, all the way to 1990. And of course either or both items could be replicas matched together from inappropriate years.

1943 model coats:
[image]

1990 government standard ГОСТ 20756—88: [image]

Comment: IIRC, Saddam Hussein was a bit of a Russophile. Is it possible that his military used these as well in some capacity?